# jQuery - How to remove class if clicking outside of div or open/close button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, addclass, removeclass

I'm fairly new to JS and I can't quite figure out how to get this to work. Any help is very much appreciated! So I have a hamburger button that, when clicked, simultaneously toggles the animation of a slide-in panel and hamburger animation by adding a class to the panel and button. I have successfully added a click event to close the panel if user clicks anywhere outside of the panel but I can't get the hamburger button to remove the added classes as well. I'd like the user to have both options (click button or click outside of panel).

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav nav--right">
  <li class="v-button--slide-right" id="toggle-menu">
    <button class="mpp-menu-icon mpp-menu-icon--cross toggle-menu">
      <span class="toggle"></span>
      <span class="menu">menu</span>
    </button>
  </li>
</ul>

<nav id="menu--slide-right" class="nav menu--slide-right">
  <ul class="main-menu">
    <li><a href="/home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav><!-- end slide menu -->
```

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var openSidebar = function() {
        $('.menu--slide-right').addClass('is-active');
        $('.toggle-menu').addClass('is-active');
        $('#toggle-menu').addClass('toggle-close');
    }
    var closeSidebar = function() {
        $('.menu--slide-right').removeClass('is-active');
        $('.toggle-menu').removeClass('is-active');
        $('#toggle-menu').removeClass('toggle-close');
    }


    $('.toggle-menu').click(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        openSidebar();
    });

    $(document).click(function(event) {
        if (!$(event.target).closest('.menu--slide-right').length) {
            closeSidebar();
        }
    });
});
```

[And here's a JSFIDDLE to demo what I have so far](https://jsfiddle.net/5ssccz2a/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very simple fix - add an "open" variable which changes to `true` when the sidebar opens, and evaluate this variable in your click event handler.

Add the variable:

```
var open = false;
```

Add the variable mutators to your open and close functions:

```
var openSidebar = function(){
    $('.menu--slide-right').addClass('is-active');
    $('.toggle-menu').addClass('is-active');
    $('#toggle-menu').addClass('toggle-close');
    open = true; //This is the new part!
}
```

Then toggle which function to call on button click - I achieve this with a ternary operator:

```
$('.toggle-menu').click( function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    var toggle = open ? closeSidebar : openSidebar;
    toggle();
});
```

Check the fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/5ssccz2a/1/)

Comment: Remember to upvote and set my answer as accepted by clicking the green arrow to the left. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: That's an ingenious solution! Good to add: for listening on the click outside the sidebar, this line is sufficient: `$(document).click(closeSidebar);`, since OP already stopped event from propagating within the sidebar.

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty way to fix this is to change your openSideBar function to use jQuery's toggleClass method, i.e.:

```
 var openSidebar = function() {
  $('.menu--slide-right').toggleClass('is-active');
  $('.toggle-menu').toggleClass('is-active');
  $('#toggle-menu').toggleClass('toggle-close');
}
```

This way when a user clicks on the button, it will toggle the class on/off, and you already have the code to turn it off when they click outside of the button.

Check it out here: https://jsfiddle.net/5ssccz2a/2/

jQuery .toggleClass(): http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and most robust way would be to check if one of your classes are active on the button. So also no extra variables are needed. I would recommend, deciding on one class to control the others.

```
$('.toggle-menu').click(function(event) {
      if ($('.toggle-menu').hasClass('is-active') {
         closeSidebar();
      }
      else {
         openSidebar();
      }
      event.stopPropagation();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Test for `.is-active` class before deciding whether to run `closeSidebar()` or `openSidebar()` when `.toggleMenu` is clicked.

```
$('.toggle-menu').click( function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    if( $(this).is('.is-active') ) {
        closeSidebar();
    } else {
        openSidebar();
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/5ssccz2a/4/)

Or, using the ternary operator:

```
$('.toggle-menu').click( function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).is('.is-active') ? closeSidebar() : openSidebar();
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/5ssccz2a/5/)